# sqlite pivot? result rows as columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm having some troubles creating a good query and need your expert help :)

I have 2 tables with data

```
Players_ingame:
## playerid ## ## week ##  ## score ##
     13            1           5
     13            2           0
     13            3           7
     07            1           0
     07            2           8
     ..            .           ..

Players_bench:
## playerid ## ## week ##  ## score ##
     07            3           2
     ..            .           ..
```

I want the result of my query like:

```
## playerid ## ## week1 ## ## week2 ## ## week3 ## ## wee... ##
     13             5           0           7           .
     07             0           8           2           .
     ..
```

How can I do this? Is it even possible?
I have a SQLite DB but can switch to MySQL if it will make a difference

please help.. many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION ALL for the 2 tables to return all the rows and then get the results with conditional aggregation:

```
select t.playerid, 
  max(case t.week when 1 then t.score end) week1,
  max(case t.week when 2 then t.score end) week2,
  max(case t.week when 3 then t.score end) week3
from (
  select * from Players_ingame
  union all
  select * from Players_bench
) t  
group by t.playerid
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8dco3Mts4GC98MMnUgC5k7/0).
Results:

```
| playerid | week1 | week2 | week3 |
| -------- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| 7        | 0     | 8     | 2     |
| 13       | 5     | 0     | 7     |
```

Comment: It it also possible to make the weeks dynamic?

Comment: SQLite does not support the PIVOT statement, so it can't be done.